# Invoke method in new thread (method name from string)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, invoke

Im trying to invoke a method on a new thread in a winforms c# app. But I need the method name to come from a string.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
public void newThread(string MethodName)
{
   new Thread(new ThreadStart(MethodName)).Start();
}
```

I've tried but cant seem to get this to work?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: First get a `MethodInfo` through reflection then execute it in another thread code to call it. Just see MSDN about `MethodInfo.Invoke` for an example

Comment: 1) What is the method's signature? Is it compatible with the non-generic `Action` delegate? 2) Is it a static method, or an instance method?

Comment: Assuming signature and visibility are compatible with what you need it's just one line: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, null));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to call method from within class itself.

```
Type classType = this.GetType();
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType)
object[] parameters = new object[] { _objval };
MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
ThreadStart threadMain = delegate () { mi.Invoke(this, parameters); };
new System.Threading.Thread(threadMain).Start();
```

If not replace `this` with class you need.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, great approach, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it can be:

```
public void NewThread(string MethodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    var mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(MethodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mi.Invoke(this, parameters), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

void Print(int i, string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + s);
}

void Dummy()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dummy Method");
}
```

---

```
NewThread("Print", 1, "test");
NewThread("Dummy");
```